# Extracting unique values from json arrays in PostgreSQL within Metabase

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, metabase

How can I select distinct values in json arrays using PostgreSQL in Metabase?

I'm using metabase.
I have a column with nest of json, and I want to extract the values using distinct.

I have a column with nest of json, and I extracted the values I wanted using json_array_elements:

```
select  (json_array_elements(metadata::json)->>'tribunal') "Tribunal" from checks  join suppliers on checks.supplier_id = suppliers.id join buyers on suppliers.buyer_id = buyers.id where checks.name = 'CRIMINAL_PROCESSES'
```

And it worked.

But now, I want to select the distinc values of the "Tribunal" couluncolumn.

And I tried two ways:

I tried to create a CTE, and then used the "SELECT DISTINCT "TRIBUNAL" FROM TABLE(CTE)"

And tried this way:

```
select distinct "Tribunal" from (
select  (json_array_elements(metadata::json)->>'tribunal') "Tribunal"
from checks 
    join suppliers on checks.supplier_id = suppliers.id
    join buyers on suppliers.buyer_id = buyers.id
where checks.name = 'CRIMINAL_PROCESSES') t
```

The two attempt returned this error message:
"ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZaOg.png)